# Can a custom GUI button contain application logic?

Tags: winforms

this is a OO design question

I am making a memory game (card, 2 selections, if right continue on, otherwise turn moves to the other player).

I have a separation between the UI layer and the logic layer. events are implemented in the logic layer to report of interesting events to the UI layer.

I have a control called ButtonCard that inherits from Button and represents a card. it contains properties that represent it's location in the gameboard (x,y)

My question is about what is the correct object-oriented way to let the logic layer know that a click has been made:

1. override the onClick method (or register to the click event within the buttonCard), and there - let the logic layer know that it has been clicked (thereby requesting it to be revealed)
2. the Form that contains all the buttonCards is registering to all of their click events, will let the logic layer know about the click

The way I see it, There are benefits and disadvantages to both ways. the first method is proper OO in that, it makes more sense for the card object to pass the information along, and why should there be a middle-man? and the middle-man could even be considered a benefit, because the logic is contained in a central designated location.

What makes more sense to you guys?

Answer (score 0):

> ...events are implemented in the logic layer to report of interesting events to the UI layer

I recommend used the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

the simple and best way..

on the C# you can use [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/awbftdfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g:

```
public class LogicLayer
{
    public event SomeEventHandler Notice = delegate{};
    ...
    protected void notify(LogLevel level)
    {
        ...
        Notice();
    }
}
...
public delegate void SomeEventHandler();

... 
//Subscribers 
LogicLayer.Notice += new SomeEventHandler(innerNotify);

... 
// UI layer:
void innerNotify()
{
    buttonCard.Text = ...
}
```

for real sample you can see, e.g.: my plugin for Visual Studio [source on C#](https://bitbucket.org/3F/vssolutionbuildevent/src/master/vsSolutionBuildEvent/)

Also see - [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Comment: I understand the idea behind observer, and it does fit; My question is whether the subscriber should be the button (representing the card) or the Form.

Comment: :) individual buttonCard's vs Form...

@Jackl56, 
In general both versions correct & convenient in certain cases - _it all depends of your application architecture!_

Choice should be made with thoughts: What possible function **in the future** can take over each of these components ? only you can know this...

e.g.: ~ the Form should not take care of all her buttonCard & each the buttonCard must take care of themselves (location, what can do, etc.)
Sample in this case - the chess game.. good luck!